# Website text unhighlightable and links unclickable in FF18 and Chrome but works fine in IE 9

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have made a website and for some reason it works in IE 9 but none of the text is highlightable in Firefox 18 or Chrome and none of the links work. I have tried changing all the divs with links to have a z index of 999 I have validated the code with W3c, I have tried changing the tags used to decorate the links and tried different css but none of it works.

I just cannot find out what is wrong and it is a mystery why it works in IE, the worst browser.

If anyone could help I would be eternally grateful. I uploaded it here

http://1400testwebsite.uphero.com/

Thank you

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 3):

Try removing "z-index: -1" from the Wrapper Div. This solved the problem in Chrome and FF for me.

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong property: #wrapper {z-index: -1}
z-index can't be negative.

Comment: Oh my god your a genius! I couldn't work it out thank you! Why did it still work in IE?

Comment: because it's "the worst browser" =)

Answer (score 1):

Remove z-index -1 from #wrapper and this will solve your problem, z-index should always be a positive number between 1 - 32767.